# Is there a systemd way to control cpu power profiles?

Tags: systemd, power-management

A lot of people suggest on i3 and swaywm to use [scripts like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04)

```
$ cat set_cpu_performance
#! /bin/bash
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "performance" > $file; done

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

And, another one for `powersave`. Is there a way to do this with systemd? It seems like there should be a simplier way to set the profile across all CPUs without needing to script it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems systemd power management is limited to hibernate, sleep, reboot, and shut down type stuff and does not extend to cpu profiles.

That said, I found a cool utility that does this `cpupower`

```
sudo cpupower -c all frequency-set -g performance
sudo cpupower -c all frequency-set -g powersave
```

More lists of tools can be be found on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the distro.
Most of the modern distros include a cpufrequtils systemd unit which can be configured to apply a governor to all CPUs.
Check [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling).